# Is it possible to get maven commands used when packaging a project?

Tags: java, maven

I wonder if it is possible to get all commands maven uses when making a package, or installing when, for example, I use:

```
mvn clean install
```

Can I somehow get a *list of used commands* ?
Something, probably, like

```
javac -d bin -sourcepath...[and so on]
```

Comment: your question is not very clear. You rune a Maven command and a maven command executes Maven plugins to accomplish the command creation. That's "all".

Comment: Maven compiles classes and makes a jar, so it doesn't do anything really special. So I'd like to have those commands

Comment: As you said, **Maven compiles classes and makes a jar, so it doesn't do anything really special**. So, I think you already know the required Java commands, for e.g, **javac something...** for compiling the code and **java -jar something...** to package. What specifically are you looking for? If you are curious as how exactly maven does compiling, packaging, etc, you can go through the source code.

Comment: I'm using plugins that are not so obvious. For example onejar-maven-plugin that is creating a jar with everything used included in it, so I want to know how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the closest you can get to this is by **enabling maven debug** (`-X` option) and check for the verbose output of each goal until you figure out the problem:

`mvn package -X`

Since you'll get tons of [DEBUG] lines, it can be interesting to redirect the output of this command to a file (e.g. *out.log*) so you can carefully inspect its content in you favorite text editor:

`mvn package -X > out.log`

As an example, check the output generated by the **compile goal** below. You can see a lot of details concerning the **javac compilation**:

```
...
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) basedir = /home/you/yourproject/
[DEBUG]   (f) buildDirectory = /home/you/yourproject/target
[DEBUG]   (f) classpathElements = [/home/you/yourproject/target/classes, /h
[DEBUG]   (f) compileSourceRoots = [/home/you/yourproject/src/main/java]
[DEBUG]   (f) compilerId = javac
[DEBUG]   (f) debug = true
[DEBUG]   (f) encoding = UTF-8
[DEBUG]   (f) failOnError = true
[DEBUG]   (f) forceJavacCompilerUse = false
[DEBUG]   (f) fork = false
[DEBUG]   (f) generatedSourcesDirectory = /home/you/yourproject/target/gene
[DEBUG]   (f) mojoExecution = org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile {execution: default-compil
[DEBUG]   (f) optimize = false
[DEBUG]   (f) outputDirectory = /home/you/yourproject/target/classes
[DEBUG]   (f) projectArtifact = org.gov.serpro:pgddirf:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG]   (f) showDeprecation = false
[DEBUG]   (f) showWarnings = false
[DEBUG]   (f) skipMultiThreadWarning = false
[DEBUG]   (f) source = 1.7
[DEBUG]   (f) staleMillis = 0
[DEBUG]   (f) target = 1.7
[DEBUG]   (f) useIncrementalCompilation = true
[DEBUG]   (f) verbose = false
[DEBUG]   (f) mavenSession = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@71a27302
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@71a27302
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Using compiler 'javac'.
[DEBUG] Source directories: [/home/you/yourproject/src/main/java]
[DEBUG] Classpath: [/home/you/yourproject/target/classes
 /home/you/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.4.01/xml-apis-1.4.01.jar
 /home/you/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.jar
 /home/you/.m2/repository/javax/javaee-api/7.0/javaee-api-7.0.jar

...
```

I hope it helps you somehow!

Comment: Thanx, looks like it's closest I can get to it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Maven `help:describe` goal.
For each lifecycle phase, you could know whether a plugin is attached to and the goal that it executes.

For example, on a Maven WAR project, running :

```
mvn help:describe -Dcmd=install
```

produces :

> It is a part of the lifecycle for the POM packaging 'war'. This
>   lifecycle includes the following phases:
>
> - validate: Not defined
> - initialize: Not defined
> - generate-sources: Not defined
> - process-sources: Not defined
> - generate-resources: Not defined
> - process-resources: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources
> - compile: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile
> - process-classes: Not defined
> - generate-test-sources: Not defined
> - process-test-sources: Not defined
> - generate-test-resources: Not defined
> - process-test-resources: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources
> - test-compile: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile
> - process-test-classes: Not defined
> - test: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test
> - prepare-package: Not defined
> - package: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war
> - pre-integration-test: Not defined
> - integration-test: Not defined
> - post-integration-test: Not defined
> - verify: Not defined
> - install: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install
> - deploy: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy

Additionally, to run the Maven command in verbose mode, specify the `-X` flag.
Note that this produces a **really very verbose** output.